# Angular SPA + .Net Core API IIS URL Rewrite

Tags: angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

On IIS, I've set up an Angular SPA with this URL `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081`. I also have a .Net Core Web Api self hosted on port 5000.

To avoid Web API exposition on internet, I would like to rewrite URL on the Angular site, let's say from `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081/api/v2/home/...` to `http://localhost:5000/api/v2/home/...`

I've tried matching url with pattern `^.*(/api/.*)$` and for action rewrite to `http://localhost:5000/{R:1}`. But this does not work.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more details? Are we talking about the application generated by the .Net Core CLI (with Angular on the top), or we talk about 2 separated microservices, i.e .Net Core standalone backend, and Angular standalone frontend?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about two standalone applications, hosted on two sites on the same server (one on IIS (SPA) the other on a windows service).

Comment: Ok. I see what you're trying to do, but isn't rewriting URL just too much hassle? I'd probably do it in service that access your API, and would probably do it like `DEV_URL = http://xxx.xxx.xxx:5000/api/v2/`, and your `PROD_URL=https://xxx.xxx.xxx/api/v2/`. You could then simply use the switch to tell it which environment you use. Alternatively you could try with pattern `^\/api\/.*$`.

Comment: Finally, i've got it to work. On IIS, I've used the Url Rewrite module but you have also to install ARR. Following part of this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818427/angular-spa-net-core-api-iis-url-rewrite. You should use a Reverse Proxy rule and all should get right. On .Net Core Web API, you will have to allow and manage CORS.